# Forgot password URL in email returns an error

Tags: users, control-panel, password

When hitting the "forgot password" link on the CP login form, an email is sent but the URL provided returns "Bad Request Param "id" doesn't exist."

Is this a bug or have I done something silly?

This is a site running on a local development environment with Craft 2.3.2636

Comment: Can you enable devMode, reproduce the issue, then immediately zip up your craft/storage/runtime/logs folder and send it to support@buildwithcraft.com?

Answer (score 3):

I know why this happens - we have the same problem. It is related to the escaping of the `&` in the password reset URL not being escaped:

```
http://yoursite/admin/actions/users/setpassword?code=abcd&id=1234
```

somehow, this arrives at our (and your I guess) server as:

```
http://yoursite/admin/actions/users/setpassword?code=abcd&amp;id=1234
```

Then the code is `abcd` and a parameter called `amp;id` is `1234`.

In our case, we have craft setup to send HTML emails, and have an email template like:

```
Click here to reset your password: {{link}}
```

and end up with the link `http://yoursite/admin/actions/users/setpassword?code=abcd&id=1234` directly in the HTML - this is *WRONG*, since the `&` symbol has to be escaped as `&amp;`.

Now, we could compensate, and make our template:

```
Click here to reset: {{link|escape}}
```

Then we get correct HTML, but the plain-text version of the email is now broken.

AFAIK there is no way to have separate templates for text and html emails in craft?

I guess your problem is also HTML emails, OR you have a user with an overzealous email client, that adds the escape of the `&` for you.

Comment: I'd like to know how to solve this, so I've asked it as a separate question:http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/how-to-encode-links-in-email-templates

Comment: So this seems to be an actual bug.